# How to use .getObjectSize in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

In Clojure, what is the best way to determine the size of a map? Import java library "java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation" and use .getObjectSize. However, the library cannot be imported. Please comment how to import the library correctly.

```
; Load the instrumentation namespace to get access to its vars
(require '[java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation :as inst])

; Find the size of an object
(println "The size of a map is"
         (inst/getObjectSize {:ts 20200101170000219 :bid 108.730000 :ask 108.786000})
         "bytes")
```

Comment: Using `java.lang.instrument.*` requires making a Java Agent to run alongside your program. There is [an example in Clojure](https://dgopstein.github.io/articles/clojure-javaagent/), though it is noted `getObjectSize` reports the size of the object only, and does not include the graph of objects that are referenced by it. Andy Fingerhut's answer below is likely to better serve your needs.

Comment: @SteffanWestcott  Thanks for your comment. we shall take a look of an example in Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used that Java library before, but note that many collections in Clojure are implemented using many Java objects, i.e. typically a "root" object that points to many other objects.  If you want to know the size of all of these, and/or create drawings showing their structure, I have created a library called `cljol` that can do this: https://github.com/jafingerhut/cljol

The README shows examples of use and the output you can expect.  There is also a link in the top level README to a gallery of other images created using the library, for a few Clojure data structures.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. cljol is an excellent tool to read the contents of Clojure collection. In our case, we want to read the size of map and use the size of map in memory mapping.